# How to read in line from file, split after the second space so name and score are separated?

Tags: java

Not sure where it is that this is throwing an exception, but basically I'm trying to isolate the score so I can call the scores in a comparable function and print out the associated name and score in order of the score.

```
public void loadDataFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String name = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ', line.indexOf(' ') + 1));
        String score = line.substring(line.indexOf(name));
        int studentScore = Integer.parseInt(score);

        Student s = new Student(name, studentScore);
        student_list.add(s);
    }
}

public void printInOrder() {
    Collections.sort(this.student_list);
    for(Student s : student_list) {
        s.toString();
    }
}
```

[Text file that I'm reading from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHc8m.png)

Comment: "Not sure where it is that this is throwing an exception" what exception do you get?

Comment: what is the full stacktrace ?, why are you using a Scanner when reading from a file?, if you are using Java 8 or higher, try Files.lines(), from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: The exception should tell you precisely where your problem is. You should also try using the debugger to step through your code

Comment: If you are using precisely the list that you provided, the error is simply that the first line cannot be parsed (since it does not contain a parsable number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you never close your `Scanner` (and you can pass a `File` to the `Scanner` constructor, so no need for a `FileReader`) - I would use `try-with-Resources` to ensure that file handle is closed. Second, you need to consume (and skip) the header in your file. Finally, I would use [`String.lastIndexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-) instead of trying to find the second space (just find the last one). Something like,

```
public void loadDataFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        if (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine(); // consume header
        }
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue; // skip empty lines.
            }
            int p = line.lastIndexOf(" ");
            String name = line.substring(0, p);
            int studentScore = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(p + 1));
            Student s = new Student(name, studentScore);
            student_list.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always worry about extra spaces.  String line = in.nextLine(); should be String line = in.nextLine().trim(); and someone adding an extra space after the number won't break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it ended up just being the issue of not grabbing the individual number, where studentScore was grabbing the whole line. I fixed and posted for other's reference.

```js
public void loadDataFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

  while ( in .hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in .nextLine();
    String name = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ', line.indexOf(' ') + 1));
    String studentScore1 = line.substring(line.length() - 2);
    int studentScore = Integer.parseInt(studentScore1);
    Student s = new Student(name, studentScore);
    student_list.add(s);
  }
}

public void printInOrder() {
  Collections.sort(this.student_list);
  for (Student s: student_list) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
  }
}
```